# Custom button not clickable on full calendar event with mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using full calendar with a custom event view (its almost the same as the default but I only added a button to delete the event

[image]

```js
        eventDidMount: function(eventDidMountInfo) {
          var $deleteBtn = $(eventDidMountInfo.el).find('button')
          if(eventDidMountInfo.event.extendedProps.can_edit_event) {
            $deleteBtn.on( "click", function(argument) {
              deleteTimeSlot(calendar, eventDidMountInfo.event)
            })
          } else {
            $deleteBtn.remove()
          }
        },
        eventContent: function(info) {
          return {
            html: '<div class="fc-event-main-frame"><div class="fc-event-time">' + info.timeText + '<button type="button" class="btn-close float-end m-1" aria-label="Close"></button></div><div class="fc-event-title-container"><div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">' + info.event.title + '</div></div></div>'
          };
```

this works well on pc, I manage to delete events without an issue, the issue is on mobile, the event isn't firing.

I'm guessing there is something to do with the full calendar feature long press on mobile?

Comment: Have you tried using touch events? Some mobile devices do no convert clicks to touch events automatically, so you have to listen for touch instead of click. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Comment: you are right! thanks! I thought was some layer being put on top of the event, but I wasn't seeing anything relevant. Do you want to convert your comment into a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile devices use the Touch Events API, not normal click events.

So we have to use both `.on( 'click' )` and `.on( 'touchstart' );` to be compatible with both PC and some mobile devices.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events